# Using Moment of Intertia Definition to Calculate Rod's Moment of Intertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

I would like to use the moment of intertia definition to calculate the moment of inertia in this problem (from 3,000 solved problems in Physics, Schaum's Outlines):

"A rod of length L is composed of a uniform length of $\frac{1}{2}L$ of wood whose mass is $m_w$ and a uniform length of $\frac{1}{2}L$ of brass whose mass is $m_b$. Find I (moment of intertia) about an axis perpendicular to the rod and through its center."

This is what I did:

$I=\frac{m_w}{\frac{1}{2}L} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}L}^0 l^2 dl+\frac{m_b}{\frac{1}{2}L} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}L} l^2 dl=\frac{1}{6}L^2(m_w+m_b)$

However, the answer is $\frac{1}{12}L^2(m_w+m_b)$, and I cannot see what I did wrong. I would really appreciate any hints as to how I thought in a wrong way here.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrals are correct;  I think it's just an integration error:
$$
\frac{m}{L/2} \int_0^{L/2} l^2 \, dl = \frac{m}{L/2} \left[ \frac{l^3}{3} \right]_0^{L/2} = \frac{m}{L/2} \left[ \frac{L^3}{24} \right] = \frac{mL^2}{12}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then it would be $\frac{mL^2}{12}+\frac{mL^2}{12}=$ my answer.

Comment: One of the $m$'s would be $m_b$;  the other would be $m_w$.  This would yield $\frac{m_b L^2}{12}+\frac{m_w L^2}{12}$, which is the desired result.